# c# - how to export large amount data export to csv in best way

Tags: c#, oracle, csv, datatable, export

I have a table which has 1500000 rows and 33 columns in Oracle Db. I want to export it to CSV file. my export function is fast and working, but when i try to load query result to DataTable, it takes hours.

How can i handle it?

```
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Load(reader); // it takes too long. i wait 6 hours and stoped it.
```

Comment: You appear to be attempting to load the entire table into memory before writing it out to CSV. You need to stream the data out to CSV.

Comment: you mean i must export OracleReader to csv? if so, how ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how, off the top of my head. Just google streaming data out of oracle, or something like that.

Comment: Did you try `while ( dr.Read() ) { ...save row to CSV file... }`?

Comment: Yes, @WernfriedDomscheit i tried but it also takes too long :(

Comment: @ozlembasal..can you try by creating batch and then execute the same method?

Comment: you can use  FileHelpers (nuget) to write to the csv file https://www.filehelpers.net/example/QuickStart/ReadWriteRecordByRecord/ (you'll have to map your table to a class first). Then you can do it in batches, in parallel (e.g. load 10000 records from OracleDataReader into memory on a reader thread, then write the batch (method WriteNexts(collection) of FileHelpers) on a writer thread.

Comment: what does "you can do it in batches" mean? @Arie

Comment: @Developer but how can batch work even program does not working :/

Comment: @ozlembasal..what exactly the issue is? I guess you have issue when you fetch records it is taking lot of time. If this is the case then dont fetch complete data in one shot. Create batch and then write to CSV.

Comment: @Developer but this export function is only one part of my program. if i create batch other function doesn't work. I don't familiar thread structure so i cannot figure it out how can i divide loading issue into threads

Comment: @ozlembasal...it will not affect your functionality. The method which is doing your export to CSV. Execute the code inside your method in loop so in this way it will break it into batch and then try to execute otherwise if you try to get all data in one shot it will definitely take time.

Comment: @ozlembasal you use DataReader to read a batch of data into e.g. some list (e.g 10000 records). The connection to DB and the DataReader is still open. This way you only have to deal with max 10000 objects in memory at one time. Then you push that batch of records to another thread that appends it to the csv file (probably the most time intensive operation in your scenario) while, at the same time, the thread reading from database can fetch next 10000 records. You save time. Plus you don't have all your data in memory at once, so there's less chance OutOfMemoryException will happen.